# Cant find where authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous() is defined

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security

I was looking through the SpringSecurityService.groovy file (part of the grails.plugins.springsecurity package) And they have some lines of code that confuse me.

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder as SCH
import org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource

class SpringSecurityService {

    /** dependency injection for authenticationTrustResolver */
    def authenticationTrustResolver

....
....

    boolean isLoggedIn() {
        def authentication = SCH.context.authentication
        authentication && !authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication)
    }

....
```

These are all the places in the file where `authenticationTrustResolver` is mentioned. My question is, where is `authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous()` defined? I've looked through the imported file, but it doesn't seem to be in there. I think that function might be giving me a bit of trouble, but I dont know how to see its code.

Answer (score 3):

Grails use the concept of Dependency Injection in Services, Controllers and TagLibs, for example. This means that you can declare an attribute (in this case `authenticationTrustResolver`) and when you use the instance of the service the instance of your dependency is already there.

[Grails plugins](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html) have a special class with the name of the plugin, where you can declare this dependencies. The name always ends with GrailsPlugin.groovy, so in this case is [SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy).

In the `doWithSpring` closure the plugin define his beans:

```
def doWithSpring = {
  ...
  /** authenticationTrustResolver */
  authenticationTrustResolver(AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl) {
    anonymousClass = conf.atr.anonymousClass
    rememberMeClass = conf.atr.rememberMeClass
  }
  ...
}
```

You can check more information about [Grails and Spring in the docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/spring.html).